# INDEX-MATCH and SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of users and the security groups they're associated with, generated from Active Directory.  It looks like this:

```
Username  Security Group
Chris     Group A
Chris     Group B
Chris     Group C
Dave      Group D
Dave      Group A
Dave      Group E
```

I have another list of usernames that I need to cross-reference to determine if a user is a part of one or more specific security groups.  The list of security  groups is dynamic and will change based on some other criteria so I'd like to just reference a named range in my check.

The equation I'm using right now looks like this:

```
=IF(INDEX('Users in Security Groups'!C:C, MATCH('Cross-Reference'!A2, 'Users in Security Groups'!B:B, 0))=Rng_SecGrp, "YES", "NO")
```

Because INDEX-MATCH stops on the first value I am getting "NO" for username that I know actually belong to these security groups I'm concerned with.  I imagine the answer lies with array formulas and/or SUMPRODUCT but both are a bit outside my comfort zone and I've failed to nail down the right formula to this point.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think you could use COUNTIFS against a range for the criteria?  I've tried this: =IF(COUNTIFS('Users in Security Groups'!B:B,A2, 'Users in Security Groups'!C:C, Rng_SecGrp), "YES", "NO"). For the moment i could make this work by doing {"1", "2", "3"} for the range criteria but this'll be a pain to maintain long-term.  If that's what it comes down to tho, then it's certainly better than manually checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() not INDEX(,MATCH()):

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS('Users in Security Groups'!C:C,Rng_SecGrp,'Users in Security Groups'!B:B,'Cross-Reference'!A2)),"YES","NO")
```

This may need to be array entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: I didn't think you could use COUNTIFS against a range for the criteria?  I've tried this: =IF(COUNTIFS('Users in Security Groups'!B:B,A2, 'Users in Security Groups'!C:C, Rng_SecGrp), "YES", "NO"). For the moment i could make this work by doing {"1", "2", "3"} for the range criteria but this'll be a pain to maintain long-term.  If that's what it comes down to tho, then it's certainly better than manually checking.

Comment: Sorry did not know it was a range of cells.  Do you want it to be and `OR` situtation, where it is true if it matches any, or an `AND` situation where it has to match all of them?

Comment: OR.  I only concerned if they match at least one, and don't care which group it is.

Comment: Perfect!  SUM!  Not SUMPRODUCT.  I knew I was in the ballpark.  Thank you very much!